# "heritance" to override a function

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding

To some extent, this is more a thought exercise than a real problem, since I don't have enough CustomFS classes to be particularly bothered by just using copy paste.  But I wonder if there's a better way.

Suppose I have several classes `CustomFS`, `CustomFS2`, etc., all of which inherit from `FS`, `FS2`, etc.  FS/FS2/etc. all inherit from `FSG`, which has a function `GetStuff`.  Assuming I do not have the ability to modify FS and FSG how can I override a particular function in many of of the FS/FS2 with only one CustomFS class, and without constructing CustomFS with FS and adding a wrapper function for all of FS's methods to customFS.

Current strategy: Copy/paste:

```
class CustomFS : FS
{
    protected override int GetStuff(int x)
    {
        int retval = base.GetStuff(x);
        return retval + 1;
    }
}

class CustomFS2 : FS2
{
    protected override int GetStuff(int x)
    {
        int retval = base.GetStuff(x);
        return retval + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: The overriding function is not really complex enough to justify adding an extra layer of indirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, except by means of a proxy or by emitting your own derived classes via Reflection.Emit.

However, if you have more complex functionality which you need to perform on each class, you might want to create a helper method (probably generic and static) which does the actual work.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, this seems like a good fit for the strategy design pattern: http://www.dofactory.com/patterns/patternstrategy.aspx

This would probably only make sense if your override function is more complex than a couple lines. But, basically, you could have a class `StuffGetter` would have its own method `GetStuff`:

```
public class StuffGetter
{
    public int GetStuff(int rawStuff)
    {
        return rawStuff + 1 // presumably, the real example is more complicated than this
    }
}
```

Then, you would do something like this:

```
class CustomFS : FS
{
    private StuffGetter _stuffGetter { get; set; }

    public CustomFS(StuffGetter stuffGetter)
    {
        _stuffGetter = stuffGetter;
    }

    protected override int GetStuff(int x)
    {
        int retval = base.GetStuff(x);
        return _stuffGetter.GetStuff(retval);
    }
}

class CustomFS2 : FS2
{
    private StuffGetter _stuffGetter { get; set; }

    public CustomFS2(StuffGetter stuffGetter)
    {
        _stuffGetter = stuffGetter;
    }

    protected override int GetStuff(int x)
    {
        int retval = base.GetStuff(x);
        return _stuffGetter.GetStuff(retval);
    }
}
```

Basically, you pass in a `StuffGetter` instance to any class that needs your custom `GetStuff` implementation. As an alternative, you could make `StuffGetter` a static class (which would save you from needing to pass in an instance), but this is less flexible. For example, if you wanted two different `GetStuff` implementations depending on the situation, using instances, you could just pass in (and store) an instance containing the implementation you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomFS : FS
{
    protected override int GetStuff(int x)
    {
        return CustomHelper.GetStuff(base.GetStuff(x));
    }
}

class CustomFS2 : FS2
{
    protected override int GetStuff(int x)
    {
        return CustomHelper.GetStuff(base.GetStuff(x));
    }
}

static class CustomHelper
{
    static int GetStuff(int x)
    {
        return x + 1;
    }
}
```